# What did mean by AttributeError at /login_user/?

Tags: django, django-models

My target is to get all the products a user added to the cart, that's why I decided to fetch the  `ShopingCart` model from the context processor. And I added it to the context processor, and it worked well. ***But the problem is when I try to log out, then I get an error.*** Where did the actual problem occur? ...

***models.py:***

```
class ShopingCart(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='UserShoppingCartRelatedName',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='ShoppingCartRelatedName',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

***context_processors:***

```
def ShoppingCart(request):
    return {"ShoppingCart":request.user.UserShoppingCartRelatedName.all()}
```

***error:***

```
AttributeError at /login_user/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'UserShoppingCartRelatedName'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_user/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'UserShoppingCartRelatedName'
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py, line 259, in inner
Python Executable:  D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site\\env',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce '
 'site\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 09 Aug 2022 11:48:23 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if user is not none and authenticated.

```
def ShoppingCart(request):
    if request.user is not None and request.user.is_authenticated():
        return {"ShoppingCart":request.user.UserShoppingCartRelatedName.all()}
    else:
         return {}
```

Comment: it has given another error,,,,,'bool' object is not callable

Comment: Oh without (). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#attributes

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are not logged in!
You must login before you can access the user atrubute.
If you are not loged in it says you are 'AnonymousUser'

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'UserShoppingCartRelatedName'
```

Login and then try it!!

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).